# How to remove brackets from $x + (-y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

How should I remove brackets like below?
$$x + (-y)$$
And why is it in brackets? Please explain me in detail how to remove brackets.

Comment: Could you please give the context of your formula.

Comment: $x-y$. There is no detail. Multiplication distributes over brackets - $(+1)(-1)=-1$ so $+(-y)=(-1)y=-y$.

Comment: Seems like $x + (-y)$ is being used, rather than the equivalent $x - y$ merely to emphasize that the additive inverse of $(y)$ is being added to $x$.  Sort of like $$x = y + 3 \implies x + (-y) = y + (-y) + 3 = 3 \implies x - y = 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

If there is a plus sign in front of a minus sign, say $x+(-y)$, we remove the brackets and the plus sign: $x-y$.

If there is a minus sign in front of a minus sign, say $x-(-y)$, we remove the brackets, and get a plus sign, since there are two negatives: $x+y$.